# Почему не работает document.onload и зачем он вообще нужен?

Tags: javascript, dom

Код, для примера:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Документ</h1>
<script>
    document.onload = function(){console.log('Документ загружен');}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Если сохранить этот код в html файл, а потом открыть его в браузере и посмотреть в DevTools, то там ничего не будет. Я уже нагуглил, что вместо этого можно использовать обработчик `window.onload` и что лучше использовать метод `addEventListener`.

Вопросы:

1. Почему функция, присвоенная `document.onload` не
   срабатывает? В понимании разработчиков браузеров, документ страницы
   загружается бесконечно?
2. Зачем нужен обработчик `document.onload`, если он не
   работает?
3. Насколько правильно вешать функцию на обработчик события
   `window.onload` или
   `window.addEventListener('load',function(){...})`? Есть
   ли какие-нибудь альтернативы или более правильный подход выполнить
   действия, когда все ресурсы на странице загрузятся?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему функция, присвоенная document.onload не срабатывает? В понимании разработчиков браузеров, документ страницы загружается бесконечно?

Потому что не `document`, а `window`. У документа есть событие `DOMContentLoaded`.

> Зачем нужен обработчик document.onload, если он не работает?

Его нет.

> Насколько правильно вешать функцию на обработчик события window.onload или window.addEventListener('load',function(){...})? Есть ли какие-нибудь альтернативы или более правильный подход выполнить действия, когда все ресурсы на странице загрузятся?

Через `addEventListener` более современно. И лучше. Почему? Потому что с его помощью можно повесить несколько обработчиков (хотя это и мало когда нужно), а через `onload` можно только одну функцию прицепить.

`DOMContentLoaded` - построено дерево DOM, `load` (на `window`, повторюсь) - загружена **вся страница**, включая все изображения и подобные ресурсы. Выбирайте исходя из своих потребностей.

Можно еще добавить, что если подключается внешний скрипт (`<script src="...">`), то можно просто добавить атрибут `defer`: `<script src="..." defer>`, что сработает аналогично `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про это. Жаль браузер не предупреждает ошибкой, что такого обработчика у document нет. Про `DOMContentLoaded` знал, но мне нужно посчитать сумму некоторых сторон картинок, поэтому, в данном случае, он мне не подходит, как я понимаю.

Comment: @Drovosek скорее всего да. А вообще можно и отдельно на картинки вешать обработчик `load`. Но там уже сами смотрите, как удобнее, на каждую картинку в отдельности или на `window` в целом.